# How to find the maximum or minimum value of a multivariable function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, lagrange-multiplier

> Determine if the function $f (x, y) = x^4 − y^2 − x^2 + y$ has a maximum or minimum value for $(x, y)$ in the range $D = \{(x, y) : x^2 \leq y \leq 1\}$ and, where appropriate, determine these.

This is how I tried solving the question:
One thing I realised is that our function is bounded by $g_1(x,y) = x^2-y$ and $g_2(x,y) = y-1$. Lets focus on $g_2$ right now, at least that is what I did. Here:

I found the Lagrange function:

$L(x,y,z) =  x^4 − y^2 − x^2 + y - λ(x^2 - y)$

$\nabla L = (4x^3 - 2x -2\lambda x, -2y+\lambda + 1, -x^2+y) = (0,0,0)$

and I get the following system of equations:

$${ \begin{cases}{4x^3 - 2x -2\lambda x = 0} \\ {-2y+\lambda + 1 = 0} \\ {-x^2+y = 0} \end{cases} }$$

$$x(4x^2 - 2 - 2\lambda)= 0 \iff x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1+\lambda}{2}}$$

$$-2y+\lambda + 1 = 0 \iff y = \frac{1+ \lambda}{2}$$

$$ -x^2+y = 0 \iff -(\pm \sqrt{\frac{1+\lambda}{2}})^2 + \frac{1+ \lambda}{2} = -\frac{1+ \lambda}{2}+\frac{1+ \lambda}{2} = 0
$$

As you can see I didn't get any solution for $\lambda$. How do solve
this? Btw the critical points are: $(\pm \frac1{\sqrt{2}}, \frac12)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that along the curve $y=x^2$ the function is constant:
$$f(x,x^2)=x^4 − (x^2)^2 − x^2 + x^2=0.$$
Indeed solving your system we find
$$
{ \begin{cases}{2x(2x^2 - 1 -\lambda) = 0} \\ {\lambda= 2y-1} \\ {y=x^2} \end{cases} }
\Leftrightarrow
{ \begin{cases}{4x(x^2 -y) = 0} \\ {\lambda= 2y-1} \\ {y=x^2} \end{cases} }
\Leftrightarrow
{ \begin{cases}{0 = 0} \\ {\lambda= 2y-1} \\ {y=x^2} \end{cases} }$$
So they are all critical points!

Since $D$ is a compact set extreme values exist and order to finish the job you should,

1. find the critical points inside $D$ by solving
   $$\nabla f(x,y)=(4x^3-2x,-2y+1)=(0,0)$$
2. investigate $f$ along the rest of the boundary of $D$, i.e. the segment $\{(x,1):x\in [-1,1]\}$:
   $$f(x,1)=x^4 − 1 − x^2 + 1=x^2(x^2-1).$$

Comment: So let me get this straight, when you said that the function is constant along the curve $y=x^2$, you are saying that I don't need to analyze if $f$ has a maximum or minimum along that edge since it is zero everywhere which means I can just pick a random point on $y=x^2$.  So now the only things I should analyze is the line y=1 right? Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Need_MathHelp Yes, it remains to analyze the line $y=1$ (to complete the investigation of $\partial D$) AND the interior of $D$.

Comment: Alright but should I always check like you did? What made you realise that the $f$ would be constant along the curve $y=x^2$?

Comment: No, also solving your system we find that all the points are critical. I noted that $f$ is constant along $y=x^2$ because of the factorization $f=(x^2-y)(x^2+y-1)$